# Recording client side audio in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to record client side audio input in angular. Does angular have a native support for that? I have tried using p5 library but it seems to be having integration issues.

Comment: https://medium.com/@coolchoudharyvijay/use-mic-in-angular-to-record-audio-simplified-1374d89718d3?sk=19a0b1c119483c99425b4f72d9a40099

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there's native angular support for that purpose. But you can use basic browser API for that.

This will start recording audio from the client, assuming he grants permissions:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();
  });
```

[Consider this article for more.](https://medium.com/@bryanjenningz/how-to-record-and-play-audio-in-javascript-faa1b2b3e49b)

Comment: I am trying to create a wav file from input. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

Comment: https://medium.com/@coolchoudharyvijay/use-mic-in-angular-to-record-audio-simplified-1374d89718d3?sk=19a0b1c119483c99425b4f72d9a40099